# boost ptime to unix timestamp conversion error

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I'am using boost date time to calculate the unix time for a particular date.
In most cases the returned value is correct but sometimes the calculated number of 
second is not correct.

This is an example :

```
boost::posix_time::ptime t(boost::gregorian::date(1900, 1, 1));

boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1));
boost::posix_time::time_duration dur;

dur = t - epoch; 

int tstamp = dur.total_seconds();

if (t < epoch) tstamp = -tstamp ;
```

The expected value is -2208902400 but I get -2085978496.
Do you have a workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason boost has the [year 2038 bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3109).

The work around is to avoid dates from before your grandparents were born :)

update: the boost bug tracker has [a bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3109) for this.  It's 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has `time_t` defined to `int` and 32-bit `int`, than earliest date representable in it is 1901-12-13T20:45:52. As Michael Slade said in the other answer, apparently boost uses 32 bits internally somewhere even if `time_t` is larger, so date 1900-01-01 does not work with `boost::posix_time::ptime`.

Comment: Not true apparently - on my system `time_t` is 64 bits and I got the 32-bit bug.  `time_t` actually isn't even mentioned in the code.  It appears to be a deficiency in boost.